# Named arguement Vs Positional argument in C#

Tags: c#, arguments, named

```
static int CalculateBMI(int weight, int height)
{
    return (weight * 703) / (height * height);
}
```

why the following line runs well,

```
Console.WriteLine(CalculateBMI(123, height: 64));
```

but the below line gives compiler errors

```
Console.WriteLine(CalculateBMI(weight: 123, 64));
```

Comment: Named arguments must come after the positional arguments, no exceptions.

Comment: Imagine it had three arguments, and to make it more fun, make them all optional and make `weight` the middle of the three arguments. For your second example, try to come up with a sensible rule for *which* of the remaining parameters 64 is intended to be for. Should it be "the first parameter that hasn't been supplied a value yet, i.e. the first" or "the next argument which follows the named argument, i.e. the third". Both of these options can be argued for, and neither one is obviously worse than the other. Why open the can of worms?

Comment: When you write down argument name its like telling the compiler "after this ill handle putting arguments in order my self", you can even change the order of arguments because you are telling the order, thats why, how ever i feel this is question that persons like eric lippert would know the exact answer ;)

Comment: Are you asking "Which language rule is the compiler enforcing?" or "Why was the language designed this way?"

Comment: (For the former, from C# 5 spec section 7.5.1, "It is an error for a positional argument to appear after a named argument in an argument-list.")